# Log in structure for iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-ios-sdk

Could somebody inform me if this is a proper way to implement a user session for an app:

If I have an iOS app where I want to provide certain functionality only to users who have logged in, and some other kind of functionality to users who haven't (say read vs. write functionality), then does the following architecture make sense...

**1)** I want to create global BOOL variable, e.g. loggedIn, that I can check against any time an app user wants to perform one of the functions under the "Authenticated-User-Only" list. I would like to know where to store this BOOL. Is NSUserDefaults best practice for storing a global boolean?

**2)** I'm trying to implement the Facebook iOS SDK, so when I return from a SSO with FB and the FB user has verified my app, can I then use that to set my global BOOL loggedIn to then be used throughout the app?

Thank you in advance.

**Note -**

This is all client-side, natively within the app. There are no webviews happening, the registry is going to query a server to return whether the user is valid or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a BOOL that's global, however that's more work then you'll have to do.

Instead, you can use the `isSessionValid` method that is provided by the Facebook iOS SDK to check if the user's session is valid.

To do this you can simply do the following in any classes that need this check to be performed:

```
YOURAPPDELEGATE *delegate = (YOURAPPDELEGATE*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

if ([appDelegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {  //Session is valid, facebook is the name of the instance of Facebook that is set in your app delegate, providing that's where you do the login handling, as per the tutorial on Facebook's developer site 
    DO STUFF
}
else { //Session is NOT valid
    DO OTHER STUFF
}
```

Comment: I'm attempting to provide two ways of logging in: Email OR Facebook. In this case does it make sense to use a global BOOL, stored in NSUserDefaults? Thanks for your response

Comment: You can use a global bool for email.  For facebook you can also use a global bool, if you want, however because the Facebook SDK provides a  way "for free" it'll make your life a little easier to use the provided way.  To do a check you could just do something like `if ([appDelegate.facebook isSessionValid] || [defaults objectForKey:@"isLoggedInViaEmail"])` where `isLoggedInViaEmail` is a bool stored in NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 3):

Matt’s answer is right-on for the existing SDK. I am adding some thoughts regarding the 3.0 revision (in beta now – and soon to be moved to the production branch.)

Derek, the scenario that you describe is common, and we wanted to make that case super simple to deal with in the SDK. In 3.0 we introduced `FBSession` to handle sessions. A single instance of `FBSession` handles a single user from login to logout.

Most applications only have a single user -- ever, so we also added a static method called `activeSession`, along with static helper methods to open the active session. (Note: the active session is not a singleton, because at different times in the execution of an application, a different instance of `FBSession` may be the active session.)

An application with authentication needs as straightforward as yours can generally do the following wherever you want to support a condition where you using Facebook Login optionally:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    // perform an operation using the open FBSession.activeSession object
}
```

The BooleanOG sample application in the SDK shows an example of this pattern, where an action in the application also results in an open-graph post, but only if there is a currently active session with Facebook. Here is a link to the relevant line of code in the sample:
[BOGFirstViewController.m](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/preview/samples/BooleanOGSample/BooleanOGSample/BOGFirstViewController.m#L146)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very helpful, and thank you for your link. However I'm going to ask the same question I asked Matt S. above. If I want to provide log in capabilities for both sign-in by email and sign-in by facebook, might it make sense to just consolidate the booleans into one global variable, perhaps stored in NSUserDefaults? (good practice?)

Comment: With multiple login schemes, a boolean doesn't strike me as the most robust solution. For example, at any time a Facebook request can invalidate a session. You may open yourself up to bugs where you either miss a Facebook notification that a session has gone invalid, or you over-respond to the Facebook failure case, when you have a perfectly fine email to fall back on.

In contrast, if you manage the two underlying schemes separately, you could write a very simple "checkLoginStatus" method, perhaps static, that checks the state of both, and returns true if at least one of them is valid.

Comment: This is the kind of advice that I was looking for. So does it make sense to define this is a global method in a singleton class? i.e. importing "checkLoginStatusFile.h" in every file that needs the method "checkLoginStatus();"?

Comment: An instance method on a singleton instance, or a public static on a class with nothing but statics, both seem fine for a simple use that isn't being published for broad reuse. Most codebases of any size end up with some helper/utility classes with nothing but statics on them that do simple common tasks -- so if you have a class like that already, you may just stash your method there.